# The function defined by $f(x)=\sin\pi x$ has zeros at every integer. Show that when $-1<a<0$ and $2<b<3$ , the bisection method converges to

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, roots, divergent-series

The function defined by $f(x)=\sin\pi x$ has zeros at every integer. Show that when $-1<a<0$ and $2<b<3$ , the bisection method converges to

**(a)** $0$, if $a+b<2$
**(b)** $2$, if $a+b>2$
**(c)** $1$, if $a+b=2$

$a$ denotes lower limit &  $b$ denotes upper limit of the interval $[a,b]$

How to consider the intervals fulfilling the conditions?

I have thought by the following way:

**(a)** $1<a+b<2$ . but if i put $f(1)=\sin\pi=0$ and $f(2)=\sin 2\pi=0$

it is not providing the different signs.

I haven't idea to solve the questions.

Comment: Please write the question in completeness, with an appropriate title. It is most helpful to not have the question carry over from the title into the body of the question.

Comment: Nobody knows the interpretation of $a$ and $b$. You have to tell us what you mean by those symbols.

Comment: @GerryMyerson $a$ denotes lower limit &  $b$ denotes upper limit of the interval $[a,b]$

Comment: @Amzoti i haven't any more information. This is an exercise of the book "Numerical Analysis" written by RICHARD L. BURDEN & J.DOUGLAS FAIRES ; 7th edition; chapter 2.1, exercise number 16.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Yes, I can't add!

Answer (score 1):

To help the OP, let me suggest a corrected version of the question:

> Consider the function $f$ defined by $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$, and the [bisection method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) based on $f$ and starting from some points $a$ and $b$ such that $-1<a<0$ and $2<b<3$. Let $c$ denote the root of $f$ this algorithm converges to. Show that $c=0$ if $a+b<2$, $c=2$ if $a+b>2$, and $c=1$ if $a+b=2$.

The first thing I would do to solve this question is to draw a sketch of the graph of $f$ on the interval $(-1,2)$. And it happens that already the first midpoint of the bisection method determines $c$... Hint: this first midpoint is either in the interval $(\frac12,1)$ or equal to $1$ or in the interval $(1,\frac32)$. What happens next, in each case?

Comment: Would you please clarify your answer? How do we know that "the first midpoint is either in the interval ... or equal to ... or ... "?

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade We know this because the midpoint of every $a$ and $b$ such that $a$ is in $(-1,0)$ and $b$ is in $(2,3)$, is in $(\frac12,\frac32)$.

Answer (score 0):

[image: graphical representation of the problem]

one can notice that $a_0$ lies in the blue region while $b_0$ hence we can establish that : $ 1\leq\frac{a_0 + b_0}{2}\leq\frac{3}{2}$ ; it is clear that after the first iteration if $a_0 + b_0 = 2$ then we get a point $c$ with $f(c) = 0$ and iteration will stop and converge to $1$.

if we say that $a+b < 2$ then we will have the point $c$ for the next iteration to the left of $1$ and the iteration will clearly keep on choosing points $c_n < 1$ and so the iteration converges to $0$.

a similar argument can be checked out for the case when $a+b > 2$ in which iteration converges to $2$ as we always stay on the right of point $(1, 0)$